# how to create symfony 2.0 eventlistner on click event

Tags: symfony, orm

I have a page with a list of questions and on every question there is link to view the details.
I want to log the event to database whenever detail link is clicked by using Symfony2 event listener

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, onClick event is not Symfony application event. It is browser event.

Secondary, Symfony 2.0 is deprecated. You should use current Symfony version: http://symfony.com/download

I assume that when view details link is clicked page should be reload.

So, you have to write evnet listener on onKernelController or whatever (it depends on your application architecture - if you provide more details I will say something more).
I can recomended monolog (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/logging/monolog.html) for logging. Yo should inject (http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/types.html) monolog to event listener and log whatever you want.

Comment: hi NHG 
i have a application for listing question and answers , jobs, and user profile, from the list page we can go to detail pages , app can be browse by logged-user and non-logged in user, so whenever logged user ckicks a details link of any object i.e, jobs aor question aor user profile . i want to log that into my db
ip, user, ob=ject and etc